# RealmSwift SyncSubscription Token

Tags: swift, realm, realm-mobile-platform

How do you add listener to your SyncSubscriptions? The code from the documentation doesn’t seem to work:

```
let results = realm.objects(Person.self).filter("age > 18")
let subscription = results.subscribe()
let subscriptionToken = subscription.observe(\.state) { state in
    switch state {
    case .creating:
        print("creating")
    case .pending:
        print("pending")
    case .complete:
        print("complete")
    case .invalidated:
        print("invalidated")
    case .error(let err):
        print("err")
}
```

This code does not execute any of those cases. Am i missing something? TIA

Comment: According to the [documentation of SyncSubscription](https://realm.io/docs/swift/3.5.0/api/Classes/SyncSubscription.html), you need to have Query-based sync enabled for your synced Realm for subscriptions to work, did you set up your synced Realm correctly?

Comment: yes, the realm is set up correctly. everything works fine, except that the statements inside the observe clause does not execute